# To add textbox to modalpop extender through javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, modalpopupextender

I  need to add dynamic textbox to a modalpopupextender through javascript,
for that i did the following

```
 function Add_Option_Panel() {
      var Var_NewRow = document.createElement("input");
      Var_NewRow.setAttribute("id","ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder2$Txt" + alpha);
      Var_New_Option.appendChild(Var_NewRow);
      $find('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_Btn_PopUp_New_Question_ModalPopupExtender').show();
}
```

The textbox gets added but the page gets refreshed and the modalpopupextender gets disappeared. I don't want it through c#. How do I make the modalpopupextender visible?